# Swift/iOS: generified UIScrollView subclass causes memory issues

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I tried to subclass `UIScrollView` and use generics on it. It has two arrays of those generified types.

```
import UIKit

class SomeView<T: NSObject, U: NSObject>: UIScrollView {

    var array1 = [T]()
    var array2 = [U]()

    override init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I tried to instantiate this class like so:

```
SomeView <NSObject, NSObject>()
```

Gives me the following error:

> *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7f9cd9612660 of class 'Swift._IndirectArrayBuffer' does not implement
>   methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead Unrecognized selector
>   -[Swift._IndirectArrayBuffer addObject:]

What the f?!

I tried lots of things, but every time I got very different errors, all seem to indicate that some weird memory issue is going on. It seems to only happen when subclassing `UIScrollView`, when I try `UIButton` or `UIView` for example there seem to be no issues...

Try it! Paste the above class in a new XCode project (iOS) and instantiate this class from the AppDelegate and you will be able to reproduce it. I tried this in:

- XCode 6.1.1 (6A2008a)
- XCode-beta 6.3 (6D520o)